# c# Null-conditional Operator

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the Null-conditional Operator (`?`) but I am not quite sure where exactly to put it `separators.Contains(textLine[(index - 1)])`. I want to say "If `(textLine[(index - 1)])` isn't null proceed". Some help?

Comment: Do you mean "if the expression is not null, call the Contains method, otherwise don't"?

Comment: ..............yes

Comment: And how should your program act in else case?

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be done, you need to use an `if`-statement.

Comment: well it's actually a bool in my case so it should just return true

Comment: operators are for expressions, flow of control are for statements.  You need flow of control (eg `if`)

Comment: Maybe with an extension method you could do `textLine[index - 1]?.IsMemberOf(separators)`. Would that be interesting to you?

Comment: yes but how does IsMemberOf work? @JeppeStigNielsen

Comment: I was thinking you could make a `public static bool IsMemberOf<T>(this T self, IEnumerable<T> setToSearch) { return setToSearch.Contains(self); }` or similar. Extension method, must be in a static non-generic non-nested class for the purpose. Then if you call it with `?.IsMemberOf(...)`, you will get a nullable bool (`bool?`) back instead of a bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to not call the contains method if the value in your array is null then you have to check it first.

```
// requires possible bounds checking
char? test = textLine?[index-1];
if (test != null && separaters.Contains(test.Value))
```

Using linq:

```
// does not require bounds checking
char test = textLine?.Skip(index-1).FirstOrDefault() ?? default(char);
if (test != default(char) && separaters.Contains(test))
```

Comment: first of all char can never be null. did you mean to write `textLine?[index-1];` instead?

Comment: yea that's what i realised now @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: That's correct i was unsure if he meant textLine would be null or the value in the array could be null

Comment: I am getting an out of range exception

Comment: You could use linq. char test = textLine?.Skip(index-1).FirstOrDefault() ?? default(char). Then test against default(char)

Comment: Or char? and ?? null if you want to test against null instead of default

Comment: The first ?. will check if testLine is null if not then it will try to return the element at index-1 if no element exist it will return a default value. ?? Is the null coalesce operator it says if the crap in on the left is null return the crap on the right instead

Comment: the problem is with the index-1 ... it can be null at times not the textLine

Comment: Index-1 isn't null its just out of bounds of the array. With the linq statement if it's out of bounds it'll just return null or whatever the default is instead of blowing up

Comment: And if you don't want to use linq then just do your own bounds checking ahead of time.

Answer (score 5):

This is not the way [Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) works.

Null-conditional Operators, only returns null instead of an exception, if one of the parents marked with prefix of ? is **== null**

**Example:**

```
var g1 = parent?.child?.child?.child; 
if (g1 != null) // TODO
```

What you need, is a simple **IF condition**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textLine))
{
    // Work here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second example of the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) should answer your question:

```
 Customer first = customers?[0];  // null if customers is null
```