# Question Mark (?) after session variable reference - What does that mean

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have had a code snippet comes to modify. In there i found this such syntax.

```
Session("LightBoxID")?.ToString()
```

I didn't understand what is that Question mark **(?)** there means. No googling helped me about any hint

Comment: Shorthand null check.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this question is not related to nullable types. Please be careful when closing questions

Comment: Null-conditional operator a.k.a. safe navigation operator a.k.a. the Elvis operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: This *is* a duplicate but it's not about nullable types at all. It's about the [Null Conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

Comment: Also you can check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524749/c-sharp-null-conditional-operator

Comment: I've created summary answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075113/what-question-mark-means-in-c-sharp-code hopefully it will start showing up in searches at some point...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What question mark means in C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075113/what-question-mark-means-in-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It performs a null-check on `Session("LightBoxID")` before attempting to call `.ToString()` on it.

MS Docs: [Null-conditional operators `?.` and `?[]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Answer (score 42):

It's the Null-Conditional Operator
It's a syntactic sugar for null checking:

```
return str?.ToString();
```

will become

```
if (str == null)
{
    return null;
}
return str.ToString();
```

Comment: Is it considered good practice to use the Null-Conditional operator?