# When to use ? instead of null

Tags: c#

Can someone explain the difference between:

```
if(object?.Count > 0){
    //code   
}
```

and:

```
if(object != null && object.Count > 0){
    //code   
}
```

Or are they doing the same thing? Thank you.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) describe the semantics pretty well. In particular, no, they are not the same thing in the case where `object` is something complicated, as the null conditional operator only evaluates its target once.

Comment: Think of `object?` as `if (object == null) return null;` - put it all together and you're effectively checking that `object != null` before attempting to call `.Count` on it. Relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074622/question-mark-after-session-variable-reference-what-does-that-mean/43074748#43074748).

Comment: I used to wonder why people answer in comments, but after getting downvoted for trying to help, I now understand.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is the null-conditional operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators). It is shorter and more precise to write if you are using C# 6 or above.